# Pytorch Dataloader can't iterate image folders

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch-dataloader

I'm trying to load this data set https://github.com/jaddoescad/ants_and_bees

However there is a error when I try to iterate the data loader

```
training_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('ants_and_bees/train', transform=transform_train)
validation_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('ants_and_bees/val', transform=transform)

training_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=20, shuffle=True)
validation_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(validation_dataset, batch_size = 20, shuffle=False)

def im_convert(tensor):
  image = tensor.cpu().clone().detach().numpy()
  image = image.transpose(1, 2, 0)
  image = image * np.array((0.5, 0.5, 0.5)) + np.array((0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
  image = image.clip(0, 1)
  return image

classes = ('ant', 'bee')

dataiter = iter(training_loader)
images, labels = next(dataiter)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 4))

for idx in np.arange(20):
  ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 10, idx+1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
  plt.imshow(im_convert(images[idx]))
  ax.set_title(classes[labels[idx].item()])
```

The error message doesn't help much, I read some similar problems here, but couldn't find a solution.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-fb882084a0d1> in <module>
      1 dataiter = iter(training_loader)
----> 2 images, labels = next(dataiter)
      3 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 4))
      4 
      5 for idx in np.arange(20):

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py in _open(self)
     64         flags = i8(s[17])
     65 
---> 66         self.size = i16(s[12:]), i16(s[14:])
     67 
     68         # validate header fields

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

The code is from this Pytorch tutorial https://github.com/rslim087a/PyTorch-for-Deep-Learning-and-Computer-Vision-Course-All-Codes-/blob/master/PyTorch%20for%20Deep%20Learning%20and%20Computer%20Vision%20Course%20(All%20Codes)/Transfer_Learning.ipynb

I'm running on Google Colab.

OBS: This seems to be a Colab problem or the python version there.
I was able to run locally with Python 3.9.13 environment.

Answer (score 0):

Add this please to your code :

```
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
   transforms.ToTensor()
```

])